# A variation of the urn-ball model

Tags: statistics

The basic urn-ball goes as follows:

Suppose there are $v$ balls and $u$ urns. Randomly(and uniformly) assign balls to urns.

Let $I_i$ be an indicator variable that $I_i=1$ if urn $i$ gets at least one ball and $I_i=0$ otherwise. $P(I_i=1)$ should be the same across all urns because of the uniformly random allocation. Let $p$ denote this probability.
$$E(I_i) = p = 1- (1-\frac{1}{u})^v$$
Note that $I_i$ is not independent with $I_j$ because an urn receiving a lot of balls will decrease the probability of other urns to gain balls.

Let $S=\sum I_i$. Then $S$ is the number of urns that get at least one ball.

Despite the dependence among $I_i$'s, $E(S)=E(\sum I_i)=\sum E(I_i)=up$

Now consider a variation.

Suppose the number of balls sent is a random variable with a binomial distribution $B(n,q)$, denoted by $V$. Then $P(I_i=1|V=v)=1- (1-\frac{1}{u})^v$.

$$
\begin{align}
E(S)  &= E_V(E(S|V=v)) \\
  &= \sum_{v=0}^{n}u(1-(1-\frac{1}{u})^v)\binom{n}{v}q^v(1-q)^{n-v}
\end{align}
$$

This is where I get lost. Is it possible to simplify this equation? For example, to get an equation like this:

$$E(S)=u(1-(1-\frac{1}{u})^{E(V)})=u(1-(1-\frac{1}{u})^{nq})$$

---

ps:
This obviously incorrect equation comes from a published paper! Note that the formula approximates the correct one when $u$ goes large.

Please refer to:

> Fontaine, François. 2007. “A Simple Matching Model with Social Networks.” Economics Letters 94 (3).

---

Or another but closely related question:
$$\sum_{v=0}^n \binom{n}{v}(aq)^v(1-q)^{n-v}=?$$
with $0 \leq a \lt 1$

I know the urn-ball model is well-studied in probability, and this extension must have been done in some paper(or some exercise of a textbook). I will appreciate any guide of related resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binomial distribution is equivalent to having $n$ balls and using each of them with probability $q$. Thus, whereas originally the probability for a given ball to end up in a given bin was $1/u$, now it's $q/u$. Everything else is the same, so

$$
E(S)=u\left(1-\left(1-\frac qu\right)^n\right)\;.
$$

On your "closely related question": This is a binomial expansion, so

$$
\sum_{v=0}^n \binom{n}{v}(aq)^v(1-q)^{n-v}=(1-q+aq)^n\;.
$$

You can use this to show that your expression for $E(S)$ yields the value above.

Comment: Can you change $U$ to $u$? I think it is better to use the lower case to represent a certain number.