# A more complicated variation of the urn-ball model

Tags: probability, statistics

see [A variation of the urn-ball model](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429135/a-variation-of-the-urn-ball-model) for basics of the urn-ball model

Now consider a tricky case:

Suppose that there are $v$ agents, each will send $a$ balls uniformly randomly to $u$ urns with a restriction that every agent must send her $a$ balls to different urns. Next step, those urns which get at least one ball randomly choose one and send this ball(or an statement says"I accept your ball") to its original owner.

For agent $i \in \{1,2,\dots,v \}$, let $I_i=1$ denote the event that $i$ gets back at least one ball(or statement) and $I_i=0$ the event that $i$ gets nothing back.

Then $S=\sum_{i=1}^v I_i$ should be the number of agent who gets at least one ball back.

The question is: $E(S)=?$

In this case, multiple urns can accept the ball from the same agent, which means, if this agent has the right to select one of these urns to reside, then the urns except the chosen one finally get no agent. The number of the finally one to one match between agents and urns should be equal to $S$.

Note that an agent does not send the balls independently. For ball $m$ and $n$ of agent $i$, the event $m$ gets returned is also dependent with the event ball $n$ gets returned(see comments below). If $u$ and $v$ are large, the dependence can be ignored.

---

For any ball, the probability of being returned should be the same because no ball and no agent is special. Let $Z$ be the number of urns with at least one ball in the end of the first step. $P(\text{a specific ball get returned}|Z=z) = \frac{z}{av}$.

The $q$ in the comments below is just $P(\text{a specific ball get returned})$. $q = \sum_Z \frac{z}{av}P(Z=z) = \frac{E(Z)}{av}$.

For agent $i$, I wonder whether the unconditional probability $P(I_i=1)$ can be approximated by $1-(1-q)^a$ if the dependence among balls of this agent is weak.

Given weak dependence, $P(I_i=1|Z=z) \approx 1-(1-\frac{z}{av})^a$, so

$$P(I_i=1) \approx \sum_Z (1-(1-\frac{z}{av})^a) P(Z=z)$$

The precise expression must be very complicated. Is $1-(1-q)^a$ a good approximation of approximation?

---

The comments after the fourth one are confusing because I did not use the concept of conditional probability to express my idea in the old versions of this question. So please ignore them. But I want to thank [joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki) for his kindness. Sorry for my abrupt writing.

---

For those who are interested in this question, please refer to

> Albrecht, James W., Pieter A. Gautier, and Susan B. Vroman. 2003. “Matching with Multiple Applications.” Economics Letters 78 (1).

Urns are job vacancies and balls are job applications. The interesting statistics is the successful match between them. I am not convinced by the argument in that paper because approximation was used extensively and implicitly and $E(Z)$ was used as if E(g(Z))=g(E(Z)).

Comment: Where you say "can send $a$ balls", I assume you mean "sends $a$ balls"?

Comment: This seems pretty hopeless to me. The probability $q$ is easy to determine -- for large numbers the returns are approximately independent, so you could use your expression $1-(1-q)^a$ as an approximation in that case.

Comment: You are right. I just modified the description. I think even for small numbers, returns should be independent for a given agent. Of course, returns should be at least weakly dependent among agents.

Comment: No, they really are dependent, as you wrote in the original post, and only approximately independent for large numbers. If one of an agent's balls is returned, that makes it less likely that other agents sent their balls to that urn, which makes it slightly more likely that they sent them to any given other urn, which makes it slightly less likely that the agent's other balls will be returned. $q$ is easily determined; it's the expected number of returned balls (i.e. the expected number of non-empty urns) divided by the number of balls.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this. But how could you use the expectation? $S$ is a non linear function of $q$, So $E(S(q)) \neq S(E(q))$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, and I don't know how to make sense of that inequality. $q$ is a probability, not a random variable; it makes no sense to take its expectation. I also don't know in which sense you're regarding $S$ as a function of $q$. I didn't say I could get $S$ from $q$; in fact I said that getting $S$ seems pretty hopeless to me. All I said was that it's easy to find $q$, and I suggested how to use linearity of expectation to do it. I don't think that this will help you much in getting $S$.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. So I also modified the linked the question to make my idea more clear: one should use conditional probability to do the calculation. In this case, because the urns with at least one ball is a random number, what you suggest is the unconditional probability of one specific ball got returned. At least, thank you for confirming my doubt that the precise expression of $E(S)$ is hard to get.

Comment: In my view, such fundamental changes in the question are disruptive. You completely removed the definition of $q$, which most of the comments referred to; no one will be able to make any sense of the comments on the basis of the current version of the question. Please consider restoring that material; you can still add to it saying why you no longer consider $q$ relevant after having initially introduced it.

Comment: You are right. I will add necessary clarification in the question. I want to keep the question concise so that new comers can easily pick up the discussion.